# Reversing an int in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm teaching myself OCaml, and the main resources I'm using for practice are some problem sets Cornell has made available from their 3110 class. One of the problems is to write a function to reverse an int (i.e: 1234 -> 4321, -1234 -> -4321, 2 -> 2, -10 -> -1 etc).

I have a working solution, but I'm concerned that it isn't exactly idiomatic OCaml:

```
let rev_int (i : int) : int =
  let rec power cnt value =
    if value / 10 = 0 then cnt 
    else power (10 * cnt) (value/10) in
  let rec aux pow temp value =
    if value <> 0 then aux (pow/10) (temp + (value mod 10 * pow)) (value / 10)
    else temp in
  aux (power 1 i) 0 i
```

It works properly in all cases as far as I can tell, but it just seems seriously "un-OCaml" to me, particularly because I'm running through the length of the int twice with two inner-functions. So I'm just wondering whether there's a more "OCaml" way to do this.

Comment: Why not int -> string -> char array -> reversed char array -> string -> reversed int? It's not OCaml but I've done similar things in SML/NJ (using implode and explode which OCaml seems to lack) while playing around with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number. Chaining together simple transformations is fairly idiomatic in Functional programming. It might entail multiple passes over the data, but "avoid premature optimization" is good advice when learning a language.

Comment: I don't see anything unidiomatic about your solution. There are probably some more clever solutions, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say, that the following is idiomatic enough.

```
(* [rev x] returns such value [y] that its decimal representation
   is a reverse of decimal representation of [x], e.g., 
   [rev 12345 = 54321] *)
let rev n = 
  let rec loop acc n =
    if n = 0 then acc 
    else loop (acc * 10 + n mod 10) (n / 10) in
  loop 0 n
```

But as Jeffrey said in a comment, your solution is quite idiomatic, although not the nicest one.

Btw, my own style, would be to write like this:

```
let rev n = 
  let rec loop acc = function
    | 0 -> acc
    | n -> loop (acc * 10 + n mod 10) (n / 10) in 
  loop 0 n
```

As I prefer pattern matching to `if/then/else`. But this is a matter of mine personal taste.

Comment: Thanks; this was along the lines of what I envisioned. Regarding the other answers, I probably should've mentioned in my post that I was trying to avoid using 'built-in' functions like string_of_int.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose you some way of doing it:

```
let decompose_int i =
  let r = i / 10 in
  i - (r * 10) , r
```

This function allows me to decompose the integer as if I had a list.
For instance `1234` is decomposed into `4` and `123`.
Then we reverse it.

```
let rec rev_int i = match decompose_int i with
  | x , 0 -> 10 , x
  | h , t ->
    let (m,r) = rev_int t in
    (10 * m, h * m + r)
```

The idea here is to return `10`, `100`, `1000`... and so on to know where to place the last digit.

---

What I wanted to do here is to treat them as I would treat lists, `decompose_int` being a `List.hd` and `List.tl` equivalent.